# How to code an inner loop to get only non-empty movie frames in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, video, movie

In my plotting code, I'm using a for loop

```
frame(S) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);    % pre-allocate frames structure

for i = 1 : round(N/S) : N

some plotting code..

axis equal 

drawnow;

frame(i) = getframe();

end
```

and then using VideoWriter:

```
video = VideoWriter('My_movie.avi', 'Uncompressed AVI');

video.FrameRate = 60;

open(video)

writeVideo(video, frame);

hold off 

close(video);
```

But I'm getting the error

> The 'cdata' field of FRAME must not be empty.

I know what the issue is but am not sure how to resolve it.

The values for i are 1,5,9,13...

which means that frames 2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12, etc would be empty.

I think I need an inner loop, just before I call the getframe() function but am not sure how to do so properly and perhaps iterate over the index.

Currently, I have tried coding this inner loop:

```
for j = 1:S

frame(j) = getframe();

end
```

However, the simulation is now running extremely slow because of this inner loop.

Comment: Why not simply do `for i = 1:S`? That way you fill in each element of `frame`. In your plotting code, if you need `i`, multiply it by `round(N/S)`.

Comment: I don't see why this would be any slower. I suspect you added a loop, this is not what I was suggesting. I've written an answer, these boxes are too small for this... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you code your loop, you are not assigning data to each frame. You pre-allocate `S` frames (frame numbers `1` through `S`), but then assign data to `S` frames with indices `1` through `N` (`N>S`). This makes no sense to me.

But it seems that you use `i` also to draw your animation, where you do want to skip "frames".

The way to do so properly is like this:

```
frame(S) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);    % pre-allocate frames structure
for j = 1:S
   i = j * round(N/S);
   % some plotting code..
   axis equal 
   drawnow;
   frame(j) = getframe();
end
```

Here, each frame in the range `1:S` is assigned data, but `i` still skips values like it does in your code.

Comment: @JalapenoNachos: I think your `axis equal` changes the size of the axes. Make sure to set the axis limits to the same values for every frame (`set(gca,'XLim',[...],'YLim',[...]); axis equal`) so that the axis size doesn't change. The alternative is to get the whole figure as a frame, which you do with `gcf` as you suggested.